# Can you tell entity framework that certain properties translate to certain names in SQL?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Given I have some Entities that have a hierarchy:

```
public class Question : BaseElement
{
    public Section Section => (Section)Parent;
}

public class Section: BaseElement
{
    public OtherThing OtherThing => (OtherThing)Parent;
}

public abstract class BaseElement
{
    public int Id { get; set }
    public virtual BaseElement Parent { get; protected set; }
}
```

Considering when I have a question and I write some linq like so:

```
var questions = dataContext.Questions.Where(q => q.Section.Id == 5);
```

It is complaining that `Question` does not have a `Section`. This is correct, it actually has a Parent. Is there an attribute that I can add to my `Section` property on `Question` so that when it is used in Linq it actually translates to "Parent" in the SQL?

I do not want to have to `.ToList()` my queries upfront as this will be inefficient and I don't want to have to say `dataContext.Questions.Where(q => q.Parent.Id == 5);` either as this is unclear especially when I will be chaining this up to five times potentially (Question.Parent.Parent.Parent etc...);

I tried `[Column("Parent")]` but it is still looking for `Section`

Comment: Yes. Check the DataAnnotation attributes. The specific attribute is `Column`. You should *not* change names from parent to child though, because you end up with both properties on the same table. Why are you doing this? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My domain has a generic list of things which have `List<BaseElement> Children` and a `BaseElement Parent`. I then have a concrete structure on top of this that is more aware of the hierarchy. As in a questions Parent is always a Section as you can see in the example above. Ideally it has to be like this because of some of the generic processing I  am doing.

Comment: No, you can't. Want it or not, you have no other option than using `Parent` accessor.in your queries.

Comment: EF is an ORM. It maps objects to tables, it doesn't transform one model to another. You are trying to map your tables *and* transform them to a completely different model at the same time.

Comment: For a question, both Parent and Section are the same thing (Section is simply cast to a more concrete class). I didn't think I was transforming anything. I am most definitely trying to map them to the same thing in sql though. I should probably mention that the DB is fine, it's all working and it is only in the case of doing queries that I am trying to avoid doing `.Parent`. As others have said it seems this is not possible out of the box. No worries.